# Is there a way to merge filter and map into single operation in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The below code will look for `"="` and then split them. If there's no `"="`, filter them away first

```
myPairStr.asSequence()
        .filter { it.contains("=") }
        .map { it.split("=") }
```

However seeing that we have both

```
        .filter { it.contains("=") }
        .map { it.split("=") }
```

Wonder if there's a single operation that could combine the operation instead of doing it separately?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `mapNotNull` instead of `map`.

```
myPairStr.asSequence().mapNotNull { it.split("=").takeIf { it.size >= 2 } }
```

The `takeIf` function will return `null` if the size of the `list` returned by `split` method is **1** i.e. if `=` is not present in the string. And `mapNotNull` will take only `non null` values and put them in the list(which is finally returned).
In your case, this solution will work. In other scenarios, the implementation(to merge `filter` & `map`) may be different.

Comment: My read of the question was that the OP was looking to leverage the fact that "=" is the parameter to both operations.  You don't use "=" for the comparison part of your answer.  No biggie though. This solution looks fine.  I think the OPs original is more readable though...easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I see your point and under the hood `split` is also doing an `indexOf`-check to get the appropriate parts.

I do not know of any such function supporting both operations in a single one, even though such a function would basically just be similar to what we have already for the `private fun split`-implementation.

So if you really want both in one step (and require that functionality more often), you may want to implement your own `splitOrNull`-function, basically copying the current (private) `split`-implementation and adapting mainly 3 parts of it (the return type `List<String>?`, a condition if `indexOf` delivers a `-1`, we just return `null`; and some default values to make it easily usable (`ignoreCase=false`, `limit=0`); marked the changes with `// added` or `// changed`):

```
fun CharSequence.splitOrNull(delimiter: String, ignoreCase: Boolean = false, limit: Int = 0): List<String>? { // changed
    require(limit >= 0, { "Limit must be non-negative, but was $limit." })

    var currentOffset = 0
    var nextIndex = indexOf(delimiter, currentOffset, ignoreCase)
    if (nextIndex == -1 || limit == 1) {
        if (currentOffset == 0 && nextIndex == -1) // added
            return null                            // added
        return listOf(this.toString())
    }

    val isLimited = limit > 0
    val result = ArrayList<String>(if (isLimited) limit.coerceAtMost(10) else 10)
    do {
        result.add(substring(currentOffset, nextIndex))
        currentOffset = nextIndex + delimiter.length
        // Do not search for next occurrence if we're reaching limit
        if (isLimited && result.size == limit - 1) break
        nextIndex = indexOf(delimiter, currentOffset, ignoreCase)
    } while (nextIndex != -1)

    result.add(substring(currentOffset, length))
    return result
}
```

Having such a function in place you can then summarize both, the `contains`/`indexOf` and the `split`, into one call:

```
myPairStr.asSequence()
         .mapNotNull {
           it.splitOrNull("=") // or: it.splitOrNull("=", limit = 2)
         }
```

Otherwise your current approach is already good enough. A variation of it would just be to check the size of the split after splitting it (basically removing the need to write `contains('=')` and just checking the expected size, e.g.:

```
myPairStr.asSequence()
         .map { it.split('=') } 
         .filter { it.size > 1 }
```

If you want to split a `$key=$value`-formats, where `value` actually could contain additional `=`, you may want to use the following instead:

```
myPairStr.asSequence()
         .map { it.split('=', limit = 2) } 
         .filter { it.size > 1 }
//       .associate { (key, value) -> key to value }
```